# TFS 2017 Builds - How to clean the workspace periodically

Tags: tfs, build

We have a "continuous integration build" definition in our TFS project. Each time there is a check-in, the source is fetched, compiled, and some automated tests are run. On the "Repository" tab of the build definition, there is a Clean option, i.e.:
[screen grab showing clean option on tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3mIb.png)
We are currently using TFVC, but are considering moving to Git.

Currently, we have the clean set to 'false', so when the build starts, the build agent does an incremental get of the source files. Throughout most of the day, this is exactly what we want since it does shorten the build times. However, it seems prudent to periodically have the agent empty the build directories, e.g. once/day. It would be nice to automate this in some way, for example if it was true whenever the $(Rev) equals 1, i.e. the first build of the day.

I've tried a few variations, entering "$(Rev) == 1" into the drop-down, or using a variable from the 'Variables' tab which takes that value, but neither seems to work. I've looked the [on-line MSDN documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/repository#build_clean_variable), but it fails to even suggest anything other than 'true' or 'false' are valid values.

I'd welcome any guesses or suggestions for further tests, or ideas.

Comment: Which version control are you using GIT or TFVC?

Comment: A workaround would be create a schedule task on the build agent to clean the source folder or add a powershell script task in your build definition to check the rev and then clean and get source.

Answer (score 1):

For now, the clean is only two option **true/false**  no matter you are using TFVC and GIT.

> **Clean:**
>
> If you set it to true, the build agent cleans the repo this way:
>
> - undo pending changes
> - scorch
>
> Set this to false if you want to define an incremental build to
> improve performance.
>
> *Tip: In this case, if you are building Visual Studio projects, on the
> Build tab, you can also uncheck the Clean check box of the Visual
> Studio Build or MSBuild step.*

You could add a [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services) here, TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion. As a workaround, you could add a [**Scheduled Build**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers#scheduled) at the end of a day do the clean repo operation.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick-MSFT. Obviously not the answer I was hoping for. Sigh. I've added a user voice so the [suggestion](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/19699258-allow-the-build-clean-selection-to-be-more-than) gets considered. I will look into the scheduled build workaround, but it isn't so obvious that I can clean up the source folder of each build on each build agent that way.